# ggplot facet_wrap reading all input data as NaN (w/in looped filter)

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm trying to generate a series of ridgeline charts from a dataset filtered according to a for loop.

```
# create list object to hold charts

print_list=list()

# loop through dataset and create charts based on facility type

for (i in data$fac_type) {

  data_filter <- filter(data, fac_type == i)

  plot <- ggplot(data=data_filter,aes(x=average,y=category, fill=category)) +
          scale_fill_manual(values= cols) +
          geom_density_ridges(
           rel_min_height=0.01,scale=0.9,
           jittered_points = TRUE,
           position=position_points_jitter(width=0.05, height=0),point_shape="|",point_size=2,point_alpha=0.7, alpha=0.7) +
          theme_ridges() +
          theme(legend.position="none",axis.text.y = element_text(angle=45, hjust=1)) +
          stat_density_ridges(quantile_lines = TRUE,alpha=0.7,scale=0.9,quantiles=2) +
          scale_x_continuous(limits=c(0,1),labels = scales::percent) +
          facet_wrap(~season)

  print_list[[i]] = plot

}

# print the charts from the list

for (i in data$fac_type) {

    data_filter <- filter(data, fac_type == i)

    filename=paste("./Charts/National - ",data_filter$fac_type,".jpeg",sep="")
        jpeg(filename,width=9,height=7,units="in",bg="white",quality=1,res=300,type=c("quartz"))

    print(print_list[[i]])

    dev.off()
}
```

When I run the above without `facet_wrap` I get happy data crunching messages `"Picking joint bandwidth of 0.0182"` and perfectly fine charts

Working unfaceted, filtered chart:
[image: Working unfaceted, filtered chart]

But implementing facet_wrap yields null datasets `"Picking joint bandwidth of NaN"` and corresponding blank facets.

Empty filtered, faceted chart:
[image: Empty filtered, faceted chart]

Curiously, the faceting works fine if I used the un-filtered data.

Working faceted unfiltered chart:
[image: Working faceted unfiltered chart]

If I insert `print(data_filter)` into the original for loop it reveals correctly filtered datasets, like below

Filtered data snippet:
[image: Filtered data snippet]

Therefore I have concluded that the problem lies with facet_wrap somehow mangling the data when it repackages the charts. Heavy Googling and Stack Overflow searching didn't yield any clues why that might be. I suspect this has to do with the inner workings of ggplot, which I'm pretty novice at.

Or suggest an alternate, more elegant way to do this? I need to repeat this operation for several sets of data so I need a scalable solution.

As a final note, I am aware it's probably more elegant to accomplish the above with lapply and custom functions – and open to suggestions how. Because of a time crunch I wasn't able to figure that out myself.

Comment: If you still want the problem solved, please try to share some reproducible data.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, the issue may be that you are filtering and/or faceting using a variable that is a factor. When you filter factors, the factor levels remain the same and this may cause issues in your faceting. If those variables are indeed factors, try adding a `droplevels()` call after filtering and see if it works.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you give an example?  

I've inserted `adm2_nat_summary_filter <- droplevels(adm2_nat_summary)` before `adm2_nat_summary_filter <- filter(adm2_nat_summary, fac_type == i)` but it makes no difference.  

Attempting the same thing with
`adm2_nat_summary_filter$fac_type <- factor(adm2_nat_summary_filter$fac_type)` is equally unproductive.

Comment: Just to note, I was never able to resolve this problem in the listed form. My workaround was to `split` the dataset on a new variable concatenating my various filter terms. Then I was able to loop on this and use facets at the same time.